# Is there any other way to mock SharedPreferences for Android tests?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing, robolectric, android-instrumentation

I'm writing UI tests for Android app with Espresso. But there is a problem, that it's impossible to mock `SharedPreferences` data. I've found some workarounds, but they are using dependency injection (Dagger2 primary).

Is there any way I can mock prefs without any dependency injections? 
Maybe exists another testing framework suitable for it?

`Edit:`
I need to mock `SharedPreferences` in instrumented, not unit tests.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/). Then you'd do this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = Robolectric.application
      .getSharedPreferences("you_custom_pref_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

From the [official website](http://robolectric.org/):

> Robolectric is a unit test framework that de-fangs the Android SDK jar so you can test-drive the development of your Android app. Tests run inside the JVM on your workstation in seconds.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. Is Robolectric tracks main thread condition?

Comment: @Alex, what you mean?

Comment: I mean automatic synchronization of test actions with the UI. Or I have to use timing workarounds like  `Thread.sleep()`?

Comment: It's a unit testing framework, not instrumented testing.

Comment: If there exists some framework, that allows me to do instrumented testing with mocking shared prefs?

Comment: @Alex, if you want to mock it, why won't you go with [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/)?

Comment: Because I don't know about suitable frameworks, that's why I asked this question ;) Thanks for the help, I'll check Mockito out.